# Maintenance more expensive for Infiniti-discontinued G25?

Tags: maintenance, nissan, infiniti, g35, g37

I recently saw a 2011 Infiniti G25 for sale at a very good price. But I've read in car forums that the maintenance for a G25 (ie. the parts for that specific model) would be more expensive since the car is discontinued.

Is this true and should I just forget about this car? I've read that the G25, except for a few options, is otherwise identical to the G35/G37.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: In general, dealership will continue to stock parts for vehicles for years after a model is discontinued. This is because they can continue to make money off of the parts. They'll continue to stock the parts for as long as it continues to be profitable. Parts being available from the aftermarket is the point at which it will stop being profitable. At which point you can usually go down to your local chain parts store and get parts for it or from online stores. Think of it this way, you can still get Pontiac parts even though the whole brand is now defunct. Really, nothing to be afraid of.

Comment: As Paulster2 said parts are still supplied - I seem to remember that they have to supply for 10 years but that may have chsnged ...

Comment: @SolarMike - It may be dependent upon where you're at. For some reason I was thinking it was 5 years here in the States ... it could be 10 years, though.

Comment: Well I can still get all the parts for mine and she is nearly 13 now...

Comment: I think the main point is that via a dealer shop, the parts may cost more. As mentioned, the tipping point is where aftermarket starts to beat-out OE parts. Getting actual OE parts can get really expensive after the model has been retired, but conversely getting aftermarket can be REALLY cheap.

Answer (score 1):

Naw, specifically in your case you will have no issues with part availability because it really is just a base package G37 with a smaller engine and in most cases will find it considerably cheaper to maintain than other cars still in production.

**Per the wiki:**

> Priced lower than the G37, the G25 was aimed to compete with entry-level luxury rivals such as the Lexus IS250, Audi A4 and BMW 328i. Compared to the G37, other than a smaller engine and fewer options (no six-speed manual transmission available, no Navigation, no Premium or Technology packages in the U.S. market), the G25 was otherwise identical and features a choice of rear-wheel drive or ATTESA all-wheel drive.

Normally you might find that because it had a limited run engine the parts we're more expensive and harder to find but its the same engine as the M25 and EX 25 which increases the volume of cars sold and therefore parts produced.

More generally almost every 10 year old car that was sold in the US but is *no longer made* will still have *parts available* for it (due to US law).

Edit: It may actually be 8 years for parts. I would have to go find the specific set of laws and court cases regarding consumer protections that spawned it to be sure.